# How to extract value from nested cURL

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to extract the data from (php)cURL response that I received from the external api. I received the response like below.

```
{"result":"OK","data":{"body":{"header":"New York, New York, United States of America","query":{"destination":{"id":"1506246","value":"New York, New York, United States of America","resolvedLocation":"CITY:1506246:UNKNOWN:UNKNOWN"}},"searchResults":{"totalCount":3661,"results":[{"id":260158,"name":"Red Carpet Inn Newark/Irvington, NJ","starRating":2.0,"urls":{},"address":{"streetAddress":"100 Union Avenue","extendedAddress":"",..........
```

Since I'd like to extract "Red Carpet Inn Newark/Irvington" from above, I changed the php curl like below, but it will not show anything now. How should I've changed it? Could anyone suggest me what is wrong with it?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxx.rapidapi.com/locations/v2/auto-complete?query=New%20York&lang=en_US&units=km",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "x-rapidapi-host: xxxxxxxx.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

// echo $response; This is origial and will show values like above.

$json = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// These are list of what I tried.   
    1.echo $json["name"];
    2.echo $json["searchResults"]["results"]["name"];
    3.
    foreach ($json['results'] as $index => $v) {
    echo $v['name'].'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode` to create an array and access the individual key.

```
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE); 
echo $array['whatever'];
```

P.S. I'm not much into PHP, but here to help.

Comment: I've been trying every possible way that I can think of based upon your answer, but I can't make it work. For example, I tried "echo $array['name'];", but It'll not show any value. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

just remove true from json_decode() and then

```
 $array = json_decode($json); 
 echo $array['whatever'];
```

It will work.

Comment: Well, no. It actually [fails with Fatal Error](https://3v4l.org/lY4NE) in currently supported PHP versions . The second parameter actually makes the `json_decode` to deserialize into `array` instead of `stdClass`.